# What is the correct endpoint for a managed released apex REST class?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I developed a managed package with namespace, let's call it "MyNameSpace" and an exposed APEX REST class, let's call it "MyEndPoint".  :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyEndPoint/')
global with sharing class ApexClass{
    @HttpPost
    global static void Send(){
    }
}
```

I install my managed released package in my test instance and I am trying to access it in postman using this endpoint :

```
https://MyInstance.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MyNameSpace/MyEndPoint/
```

But I am getting this error:

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "Could not find a match for URL"
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is case sensitive

Comment: Also, if you are using a Force.com site, and it has a suffix e.g. actions, that would form part of the URL before the Services

Comment: If you open the developer workbench and go to REST Explorer, can you see your custom endpoints listed under `/services/apexrest/`?

Comment: @identigral no it doesn't work, I tried that URL already.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC can you provide an example?

Comment: @nbrown in workbench it say "Service not found at: /services/apexrest/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up a site like this one below, and add a suffix to the default web address, and the namespace is kwac, then the REST URL would be something like this:
http://act272b-actdemobeta1.cs196.force.com/actions/services/apexrest/kwac/MyEndPoint

[image]

Comment: Well it turn out I set up the name wrong, stupid mistake, I'll leave this up for people in the future who might be searching for answer.